# Should we make WBS a tag synonym for Work Breakdown Structure?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

While I have access to Moderation Tools, apparently I am still unable to recommend tag synonyms. We have a well-defined [work-breakdown-structure](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-breakdown-structure) tag, but I think it would be beneficial to make [wbs](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wbs) a synonym since it's shorter to type.

Do we have a consensus on this? If so, can someone with sufficient privileges make it happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went ahead and merged the tags and created [wbs](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wbs) as the synonym of [work-breakdown-structure](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-breakdown-structure).

I'm not an expert on tag synonyms, but it looks like anyone with 1250 reputation can propose or vote to approve a synonym. The [privileges page on suggesting tag synonyms](https://pm.stackexchange.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) has more details.

Comment: It wouldn't give me the option, so thank you for taking care of it.